# An investor invests $5200 in two mutual funds.

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

I've been having a tough time with this one. Every time I work the equation out it is either a negative amount, or is much larger than the original invested amount. Please Help.

An investor invested a total of **5200** in two mutual funds. One fund earned **6%** profit and the other fund earned **3%**. The Total profit was **$84**. How much was invested in each mutual fund?

What I have so far:

> **x+y=5200**
>
> **.06x+.03y=84**

*Note:Then I solve by substitution. Please tell me if I'm crazy, but it doesn't seem to have the correct numbers for the equation to be properly solved.*

Comment: If you but all of the money in the lower returning investment, you still make more than $ 84.  So, yes, something is either broken, or missing from the set up.

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense. $3\%$ of $5200$ is $156$ so the $84$ is much too small.

Comment: Note:  if you assume this was just a six month investment then the numbers work and the answers are pleasant integers.  Are you sure this wasn't the question?

Comment: @lulu I am sure. It doesn't state anything regarding time or length of investment.

Comment: Ok, but with that assumption the answers come out $(400,4800)$ which seems way too nice to be an accident.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are both positive, you would expect the overall profit rate to be between $3\%$ and $6\%$

But $84$ is about $1.6\%$ of $5200$, so you will not get sensible solutions: $x$ must be negative (selling short?) to get this kind of result

Or perhaps lulu is correct and the profit rates have been annualised, and in fact were $3\%$ and $1.5\%$ over half a year, in which case $1.6\%$ combination would work, with $y$ much bigger than $x$